# Regex to find encoded string in a URL in java

Tags: java, regex, encoding

I need to find whether the URL is encoded or not. As the input is dynamic it will be helpful if i know the regex to check it.

example -
 www.test.com/?t=%E3%83%81%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by *encoded* ? Can you show us some examples ?

Comment: Probably he means, e.g., space changed to `%20`. ;)

Comment: What input? What URL? Please post code and explain what you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [URLDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to check whether the URL contained encoded parts or not rather than building a custom regular expression:

```
class UrlTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
                String url = "http://example.com/%20foo";

                if(url.equals(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"))) {
                        System.out.println("URL didn't contain encoded parts.");
                } else {
                        System.out.println("URL contained encoded parts.");                                                                                                                                
                }                                                                                                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: You should also catch IllegalArgumentException. Indeed, if the input URL is not encoded, it might contains illegal characters or sequences of characters...

Comment: i need to encode any string in the URL which is already encoded. I should not encode the entire url.

Comment: there is no way to tell whenever text is URL encoded - it could contain %20 as normal content

Comment: URLEncoder/URLDecoder arent meant for URL encoding/decoding. They are badly named classes. They are actually meant for form-encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

// regex for attempting to use any URL encoding, or .. for directory traversal

.*%[0-9a-fA-F]+|\.\.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking because **you want to encode the url if it is not already encoded**, then the easiest thing to do is **decode it then encode it again**. That way you are guaranteed to end up with an encoded url.

Comment: i need to encode any string in the URL which is already encoded. I should not encode the entire url.

Comment: Sure, so construct a java.net.URL, extract our all the component parts (path & query string), encode each element appropriately and tie it all back together again.

Answer (score -5):

Just look for a '%' followed by [0-F] - you'll know.

Comment: for example the url is www.test.com/?t=%E3%83%81%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

Comment: Really?  A downvote without a better answer - very productive.

Comment: And what about the hexadecimal numbers A..F?

Comment: I voted down since the answer is either wrong or incomplete. Pick your flavor.